# Definition of outward-pointing unit normal vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am to trying to understand the Divergence Theorem. This say:

**Theorem.** Let $(M,g)$ be a oriented Riemannian manifold with boundary. For any compactly supported smooth vector field $X$ on $M$,

\begin{equation}
\int_{M}(\text{div} X) dV_{g} = \int_{\partial M} \langle X , N \rangle_{g} dV _\widetilde{g},
\end{equation}

where **$N$ is the outward-pointing unit normal vector field along $\partial M$** and $\widetilde{g}$ is the induced Riemannian metric on $\partial M$.

I don't  know what is the outward-pointing unit normal vector field. In fact, up to this point I haven't even had a need to know what it means an unit normal vector field along $\partial M$. Intuitively, I think that means that

\begin{equation}
\langle v , N_{p} \rangle_{g} = 0 \;\; \forall v \in T_{p} \partial M, \;\;  \forall p \in \partial M,
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\langle N_{p} , N_{p} \rangle_{g} = 1 \;\; \forall p \in \partial M.
\end{equation}

I think so, but honestly I have never seen the formal definition of unit normal vector field, much less than outward-pointing.

What is the correct meaning of this?

P.S. I saw the above theorem in John Lee's Introduction to Smooth manifolds, but couldn't find the definition I needed.

Comment: the definition of the outward pointing normal appears in page 118 (second edition of the book)

Comment: there is an exercise need to prove the existence of outward normal v.f along the boundary see Problem 8.4.The rough idea is construct it inside coordinate chart,then gluing them together.